# Identify kind of descriptive role playing game for self-discovery

Tags: psychoanalysis

There's a comic book called "Knights of the Dinner Table" about a bunch of rpg players.

In one issue, the only girl at the table GM's some kind of self-discovery game she learnt in her psychology class. She describes some situations and asks for details from the players, giving an example herself.

At one point, for example, she says:

> Ok, so you continue your journey down your own personal path. Soon you come to a large bear! What do you do? My bear turns out to be very tame and I'm able to hand feed it and befriend it! He decides to accompany me on my journey.

At the end, she explains what each thing symbolizes:

> The bear represents adversity and how you deal with it

Supposedly this is (loosely) based on a real exercise for self discovery. I would like to know more about the real exercise in which this is based, but I don't know how to start.

Any idea how this exercise is called, or how can I find more information about something similar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found it, apparently it's called [The Forest Test](https://exploringyourmind.com/the-forest-test-and-its-place-in-psychoanalysis/)

> Hindrances and annoyances that take away our happiness, entrenched
> fears, values ​​that govern our choices and behavior. The forest test
> tries to clarify and interpret many of these issues based on the
> approach from which it was designed: relational psychoanalysis.
> According to this theory, our psychological suffering is rooted in
> underlying issues that we must bring to light in order to heal the
> hurts and move forward.
>
> For those who have not heard about this relational test, we should
> first say that it isn’t in any way conventional. The forest test
> doesn’t have enough reliability and validity to be part of normal
> clinical practice. However, we cannot rule out its relevance within
> the context and the theoretical framework from which it was created.
> It is, without a doubt, worth taking into account.
>
> The forest test is a projective test which can reveal the fears, hindrances and deepest interests of each patient.

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question! Note that psychoanalysis for a big part is considered pseudoscience nowadays, but, of course we still welcome questions about it such as this here.

Comment: Thank you @StevenJeuris, I know that already. I find this test very interesting and would like to know more about its history, but I don't find much information about it (lots of variants, some with an esoteric twist, to answer questions about the future, but little else)